# IllegalStateException in File Download Dialog

Tags: java, struts2, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to code a simple Struts2 class to download a video file. It works OK except when I choose to cancel the download in the download dialog, because a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` is thrown (the page works correctly, the exception is logged).

Here is the class:

```
public class FileDownloaderAction extends ActionSupport {

/** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/** The relative route to the file to download. */
private String relRoute;

/** The name of the file to download. */
private String fileName;

/** The InputStream to be downloaded. */
private InputStream fileStreamToDownload;

/** The size of the file to download. */
private long fileSize;

@Override
public final String execute() throws Exception {
    MyUtils mu = new MyUtils();

    try {
        File file = mu.getFile(relRoute + fileName);

        if (file != null) {
            fileStreamToDownload = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileSize = file.length();

            return Action.SUCCESS;
        } else {
            return Action.ERROR;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Action.ERROR;
    }
}

/** Sets the content disposition.
 * @return the content disposition.
 */
public final String getContentDisposition() {
    return "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"";
}

/**
 * @return the relRoute
 */
public final String getRelRoute() {
    return relRoute;
}

/**
 * @param mRelRoute the relRoute to set
 */
public final void setRelRoute(final String mRelRoute) {
    this.relRoute = mRelRoute;
}

/**
 * @return the fileStreamToDownload
 */
public final InputStream getFileStreamToDownload() {
    return fileStreamToDownload;
}

/**
 * @param mFileStreamToDownload the fileStreamToDownload to set
 */
public final void setFileStreamToDownload(final InputStream mFileStreamToDownload) {
    this.fileStreamToDownload = mFileStreamToDownload;
}

/**
 * @return the fileName
 */
public final String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

/**
 * @param mFileName the fileName to set
 */
public final void setFileName(final String mFileName) {
    this.fileName = mFileName;
}

/**
 * @return the fileSize
 */
public final long getFileSize() {
    return fileSize;
}

/**
 * @param mFileSize the fileSize to set
 */
public final void setFileSize(final long mFileSize) {
    this.fileSize = mFileSize;
}
```

}

On the other hand, the action defined in the **struts.xml** file:

```
<action name="downloadFile" class="org.test.action.FileDownloaderAction" method="execute">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
        <param name="inputName">fileStreamToDownload</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">${contentDisposition}</param>
        <param name="contentLength">${fileSize}</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
        <param name="allowCaching">true</param>
        <param name="contentCharSet">UTF-8</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

This code is based on some examples I have found. Tomcat prints this when the exception is thrown:

```
abr 28, 2013 12:11:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() para servlet default lanzó excepción java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:407)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:867)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:569)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Is there a way to avoid this exception?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you hitting cancel button, r you sending any server side request?

Comment: I believe not. As @dev-blanked has written, when I click on Cancel it is happening on the client side, meanwhile the server keeps sending me the data, so the exception happens. Also, the [Stream Result page](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/stream-result.html) doesn't help a lot...

Comment: @dcordonu you could prevent the outputing exception by telling the dispatcher to not send errors. Anyway handling the exception is possible via the exception interceptor. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213900/there-is-no-action-mapped-for-action-name-index-how-to-catch-the-exception-bec/16214532#16214532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save/Cancel dialog appears from the browser when you write the file (in your case Video) data to the response. Browser detects that this is a file and offers the file save dialog box to the user. When user chooses cancel the connection from the browser to the server is cancelled and thus when the server is trying to write the rest of the file to the response this exception is logged. This behaviour is valid I believe. Since the cancel action is entirely happening on the client side (that is within the browser) there is nothing you could do from the server.

Comment: OK, that makes sense but, is there a way to monitor this and avoid the exception to be logged? Or, at least, to write a custom text instead of the full error trace.

Comment: @dcordonu well the same exception could come in other scenarios as well. May be you could just log that the download video action has been called. So when one goes through the logs and finds the above stacktrace and finds above that a log saying video download was executed.. may be it could be concluded that the cancel button was clicked

Comment: Yes, you're right. But, how can I detect that the user has clicked the 'Cancel' button?

Comment: You might not be able to detect that. In your execute method just have logs stating video download initiated or something. If the stacktrace follows that log statement one can assume the user has clicked the 'cancel' button